# how to read response body in catch block in http call angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I read the response body in catch block of angular 2 http request. Following is the code that I have so far:

```
requeueTask(data): Observable<Response>{
        this.setHeaders();
        let url = SharedService.requeueTaskApi;
        return this._http.put(url, data, {headers: this.headers})
                    .map((response: Response) => response)
                    //.do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
                    .catch((error: any, response) => {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (error.status < 400 ||  error.status ===500) {
                            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                        }
                    })
    }
```

Comment: use error.json()

Answer (score 4):

You can catch error like this below:

```
return this._http.put(url, data, {headers: this.headers})
                .map((response: Response) => response)
                .catch((error: Response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (error.status < 400 ||  error.status ===500) {
                        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Hi, my error response is already in json and I don't have .error attribute, the error message is in _body... I have return this? Example: return Observable.throw(error._body || 'Server error');